# How do I use the 'When' method in ASP.NET MVC Fluent Validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I am trying to develop a fluent valiation rule where if my `TitleId` FK property is null, then the `TitleOther` text field becomes mandatory. I have tried several combinations and orders of fluent expressions, all to no avail.

This is what I have so far, if someone can please help me get this one `When` part correct, I would be most grateful, and a little more educated.

```
context.RulesFor(p => p.TitleId).Required(p => p.Message("Title is required."));
context.RulesFor(p => p.TitleOther)
        .Required(p => p.Message("Please provide your other title."))
        .Length(0, 50, c => c.Message("Other title may not exceed 50 characters")
        .When(p => context.RulesFor(p => p.TitleId). *[what here?]*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used `FluentValidation` much, but from what I understand from the [docs](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customising&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#WhenUnless) you would need to do

`.When(p => p.TitleId == null)`

instead of `.When(p => context.RulesFor(p => p.TitleId). *[what here?]*`

Answer (score 0):

I have used `When` in my project in `Fluent Validation`. I have used for 1 condition that is compare password as like below:

```
RuleFor(u => u.Password).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please Enter Password"); // Normal checked for non empty

When(u => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.Password) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.ComfirmPassword), () =>
            {
                RuleFor(u => u.ComfirmPassword).Equal(x => x.Password).WithMessage("Password does not match");
            }); // For compare password
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.